# Apply PanoTools alignment to individual images

Tags: image-processing

I have batch of images (timelapse fotos) which I aligned using 
align_image_stack from PanoTools, because the have some small shifts. The required positional shift relative to the first image is specified as roll/pitch/yaw values in the output PTO file. How is it possible to apply excatly these positional shifts to the images? I mean if it gets shifted to the right for example, then it gets some (black) border at the left and cropped off at the right.
Then I could afterwards crop out the area inside the border to get an unshifted timelapse.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the -a option of align_image_stack does this!